# Python aiohttp motorengine

Tags: python, aiohttp, motorengine

I'm trying to make basic register api but I have some problems with `motorengine` and `aiohttp`.

Can someone give me examples on how that works ?

#### Here's my code :

```py
from motorengine.connection import connect
from motorengine.document import Document
from motorengine.fields import StringField, DateTimeField

from aiohttp import web
import asyncio

import json


dbAdress = "mongodb+srv://test:Z1PKIdwMVNPA63Em@cluster0-0ehjt.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
client = connect("test", dbAdress)

class Members(Document):
    __collection__ = "Members"

    name = StringField(required=True)
    password = StringField(required=True)
    register_date = DateTimeField(auto_now_on_insert=True)


async def index(request):
    response = {"status": "success"}
    return web.Response(text=json.dumps(response), status=200)


async def register(request):
    print(1)
    try:
        data = await request.json()

        print(data)
        username = data['username']
        password = data['password']

        print(username)

        if(username == "" or password == ""):
            raise KeyError
        
        print(Members.objects.filter(username=username))

        return web.Response(status=200)
    except KeyError:
        return web.Response(status=401)

app = web.Application()
app.add_routes([web.get("/", index),
                web.post("/register", register)])

web.run_app(app)
```

Comment: Can you please share information on what error are you getting? or what is blocking for you?

Comment: When I tried running this code, I got `ImportError: cannot import name 'return_future' from 'tornado.concurrent' ` error, On debugging, it seems like library tornado is now not supporting `return_future`. One option could be instead of motorengire, you can go for any other library.

Comment: Motorengine does [not](https://github.com/heynemann/motorengine/issues/109) suport asyncio/aiohttp at the moment; you can use the underlying library ([motor](https://motor.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api-asyncio/aiohttp.html)) or another library.

Comment: Can you give me example how to save data with motor.aiohttp? i tryin' this before but code got stuck and is hard to understand how to to make this works

Comment: There is a complete tutorial for it on Motor's [docs](https://motor.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial-asyncio.html#a-web-application-with-aiohttp)